# How to make a dashed or dotted line in Swift 4

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I've been trying to do this in a playground like this:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x:10,y:10))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:290,y:10))
path.lineWidth = 2

let dashPattern : [CGFloat] = [0, 16] 
path.setLineDash(dashPattern, count: 2, phase: 0)
path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round
path.lineCapStyle = .butt
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width:300, height:20), false, 2)
path.stroke()

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.captureValue(value: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(), withIdentifier: "image")
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

But the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) A dash pattern of `[0, 16]` doesn't make sense in my opinion. Both values should be greater than 0.

2) Aside from that, your code is correct, but the playground preview for the `UIBezierPath` in Xcode ignores the dash pattern (just like it ignores colors and many other settings — it just displays the path in an abstract way).

If you render the path into an image, the dash pattern becomes visible. Here's the code I used (I changed the dash pattern array to `[16,16]`):

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x:10,y:10))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:290,y:10))
path.lineWidth = 2

let dashPattern : [CGFloat] = [16, 16]
path.setLineDash(dashPattern, count: 2, phase: 0)
path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round
path.lineCapStyle = .butt

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 20))
let image = renderer.image { context in
    path.stroke()
}
// image now contains an image of the path
```